# 女 in 嫩 : combining characters

Tags: vocabulary, history, character-components

So I just learned a new vocabulary called 嫩.   An example from a YouTube channel was given as 这块儿牛肉非常嫩 to mean “This piece of beef is very tender”.

As I understand many Chinese characters can come from combining more than one individual character.  So in the 嫩, does the 女 on the left have anything to do with 女 gender at all?

Comment: yeah, in the olden times Chinese considered women are soft and tender and men are hard and tough

Comment: Be careful when using this word. Though it means tenderness, softness, delicate, it is meant to be used on "things", like your example "beef", and not on humans. Do not say that a female is 嫩 because it has sexual connotations, meaning she is "tender" to the touch.

Comment: 嫩 is used as a code for 'young' or 'inexperience'

Comment: @TangHo Wow, good to know!

Comment: @WayneCheah, ha ha no, I will not attempt to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the answer is yes. 女 is a semantic component *women*.

We haven't found this glyph in oracle bone script or bronze inscriptions; the earliest is in the Small Seal Script. It was originally written as 媆. It's both ideogrammic and phono-semantic. The semantic components are 女、耎, and 耎 gives the sound. 耎 is again both ideogrammic and phono-semantic. The semantic components are 而、大, and 而 gives the sound.

As semantic components, in general, 女 refers to women, 而 refers to beard, and 大 refers to person/human. 耎 means *0) with very very long beard*. It's extended to mean *1) front-end slightly larger than the other end* and *2) tender*. However, meanings 0) and 1) are rarely used. Meaning 2) is also written as 媆, which strengthens the meaning with women, who are characterized as tender.

媆, writing as 女而大 and undergoing some catachresis （訛變）, finally became 嫩.

[image]